# To check login session Id after login in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

***I m going to check current user id and get info is male or female but condn false***

```
public function profile() {
    $this->load->view('header');
    $uname = $this->session->userdata('uname');
    $row = $this->brid_groom_fetch->get_program_specific_gender();
    if ($row['uname']->uname == $uname) {
        $session_id = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
        var_dump($session_id);
    } else {
        echo 'fail';
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to add some more details to answer this. The controller method has no errors. Is `brid_groom_fetch` a model or a library? How does that method look? How is the session set? Do you get any errors?

Comment: i get session data Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1464684288 [logged] => 1 [uname] => test@abc.com [logged_in] => 1 )

Comment: and db data ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1464684288 [logged] => 1 [uname] => test@abc.com [logged_in] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [bride_grum_id] => 1 [name] => admin@2016 [complexion] => ssssssss

Comment: session is set and db data also fetch

Comment: Message: Undefined index: uname

Filename: controllers/user_controller.php this erreor occured

Comment: alexander.polomodov:can you reply me i stuck from yestarday

Comment: Does the method `get_program_specific_gender()` return an array?

Comment: yes return array  this is array output ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1464684288 [logged] => 1 [uname] => test@abc.com [logged_in] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [bride_grum_id] => 1 [name] => admin@2016 [complexion] => ssssssss

Comment: Then shouldn't row 5 in your code be `if ($row['uname'] == $uname) {` ?

Comment: 1 [uname] => test@abc.com [upassword] => 12345 ) ) this  uname result return array

Comment: what is the relation of row 5 and program error

Comment: Because You use the index uname there... You are checking the array index `uname` for `$row` as a class containing the object `uname`. The error indicates that the data has another form.

Comment: so , what can i use there

Comment: no one will help i done my works perfect

Comment: In my first comment I asked for more info. If you show your underlying code it will be much easier to help you. Funny that you say perfect, then there would be no errors?

Answer (score 0):

Do Not use any array object stdClass containing  variable simply check both var

```
public function profile() {
    $this->load->view('header');
    //     print_r($uname);
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        //get Data from db
        $row = $this->brid_groom_fetch->get_program_specific_gender();
     //get session Id 
        $uname = $this->session->userdata();
        //compare both variable directly don't use array format to compare
        if ($row = $uname) {
            $session_id = $this->session->userdata();
            var_dump($session_id);
        }
    }
}
```